# Real life example for second law of thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-chemistry

Is there any real life example that can illustrate the Kelvin - Planck's statement of the second law of thermodynamics?

Comment: Since the  Kelvin–Planck statement is a statement regarding something that cannot be done, I'm not sure what you mean by a real life example. Could you please clarify more specifically what you are trying to understand? Do you just need a clarification of what the Kelvin–Planck statement means, and not necessarily a real life example?

Comment: If someone needs a reminder: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelvin%E2%80%93Planck_statement

Comment: I do understand what the statement means. But I just want to know, is there any example that works on the principle of the kelvin - Planck's statement of the second law of thermodynamics. To be clear, consider the example that explains the Clausius statement. A cup of hot water can be cooled to the room temperature by emitting heat to the surroundings where as a cup of cold water cannot be heated by taking heat from the surroundings. So, I want to know if there is any similar example for the Kevin - Planck's statement

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, your question is logically problematic. The only way to practically demonstrate that something is impossible is to show that every conceivable attempt fails. This is one reason that theory is used, because otherwise you could spend an infinite amount of time trying different experiments and still fail to show it's impossible. To contradict a general statement, all that is required is one counter-example. However, there are plenty of real world examples where the efficiency (1 - work out/heat in) is demonstrated to be far less than 100%, and there are (of course) no known counter-examples. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_engine for a lot of examples. Contrast the statement of the 2nd Law with the statement that "Man cannot fly". It took tens of thousands of years to build a machine which enabled man to fly (1961) see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human-powered_aircraft#First_flights, but once it had been documented the statement became false.